# Django POSTGIS multipolygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geodjango

Why `PostGIS` does not validate the `longitude` and `latitude` for a `GEOMETRY` field when we try to save values with `latitude` greater than 90 (`latitude > 90`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

You can see that the latitude value ranges between `[-90, 90]`.
Theoretically you can have latitude `> 90` or `< -90` but that [will correspond to an equivalent coordinate with an inverse longitude](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Degrees).

That would possibly lead to the creation of 2 or more different entries with the same coordinates, thus PostGIS does not validate latitude outside of the [-90, 90] range.